# Error Updating Recycler View Item Button Visibility outside Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My goal is to have button inside each RecyclerView item that will appear on click so Im changing the buttons visibility. On the first click it works fine but on clicking again or in any other item it crashes the app.

[image: This is the Error im getting]

This is my Adapter.kt

```
class Adapter (private val orders:ArrayList<Order>, private val listener : OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>(){


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_pedido,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = orders[position]
        holder.nrPedido.text = currentItem.id.toString()
        holder.distancia.text = currentItem.distancia.toString()+"km"
        holder.estado.text = currentItem.estado


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return orders.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
    View.OnClickListener{

        val nrPedido : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewIDPedido)
        val distancia : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDistancia)
        val estado : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEstado)
        val buttonEstado : Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonEstado)
        val buttonAceitarRecusar : Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAceitarRecusar)
        val buttonDados : Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDados)

        init {
             itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            val holder = ViewHolder(itemView)
            val order = orders[adapterPosition]
            val position = adapterPosition
            if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && order != null) {
                listener.onItemClick(order,position,holder)
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(order: Order,position: Int,holder: ViewHolder)
    }
}
```

This Is  my mainActivity where the onItemClick Method is being called

```
override fun onItemClick(order: Order,position:Int,holder: Adapter.ViewHolder) {
        visible = visible?.not()
        if(arrayListPedidos.contains(order)){
            val clickedItem = arrayListPedidos[position]
            if(visible==true){
                holder.buttonDados.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            }else{
                holder.buttonDados.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }else if(arrayListMeusPedidos.contains(order)){
            val clickedItem = arrayListMeusPedidos[position]
            if(visible==true){
                holder.buttonDados.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            }else{
                holder.buttonDados.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }

    }
```

I think it could be something to do with not notifying that the item is being updated, but it could also be the way im sending the holder.
When I click one time on the item it changed the visibility to visible. If I click again (to make it invisible) or if I click in any other item it crashed the app.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the `ViewHolder` as a highly volatile view, you don't want to keep any references about it that you use outside the `Adapter` – I see that you pass the `ViewHolder` back into the `MainActivity` if I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve could be done by doing something like this:

```
class Adapter(
    private val orders: ArrayList<Order>,
    // Note: Modern callbacks are declared like this, don't worry about passing the
    // OnItemClickListener
    private val listener: ((Order) -> Unit)
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> { // Note: Try to use your own ViewHolders

    // In situations like this you can use a map or some other data structure to keep track of what
    // order button is supposed to be visible or not. You could also keep track of this in the Order
    // class itself.
    private val isVisibleMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Boolean>().apply {
        orders.forEachIndexed { index, _ -> put(index, false) }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_pedido,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = orders[position]
        // You must set the visibility during the binding
        holder.buttonDados.visibility = if (isVisibleMap[position]) {
            View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            View.GONE
        }
        holder.nrPedido.text = currentItem.id.toString()
        holder.distancia.text = currentItem.distancia.toString()+"km"
        holder.estado.text = currentItem.estado
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            // Here we update the visibility
            isVisibleMap[position] = !isVisibleMap[position]
            listener.invoke(currentItem)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return orders.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val nrPedido : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewIDPedido)
        val distancia : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDistancia)
        val estado : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEstado)
        val buttonEstado : Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonEstado)
        val buttonAceitarRecusar : Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAceitarRecusar)
        val buttonDados : Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDados)
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that things like this, changing the visibility of an item from the adapter, should be handled within the adapter itself. Hope it helps!

**Edit:** If you want to change the button visibility programmatically from outside the Adapter, you can always do something like:

```
class Adapter ... {

fun changeButtonVisibility(isVisible: Boolean, pos: Int) {
  isVisibleMap[pos] = isVisible
  notifyItemChanged(pos)
} 

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I’ll try it out. But if I want to change the button visibility outside the adapter or atleast trigger a change on a button from outside the adapter , don’t I need a reference to the holder on the MainActivity ? I understood the changes you’ve made and that view holder changes should be kept within the adapter. But can’t I treat the button like I do with data and for example in the MainActivity trigger a visibility change on the button and then notify the adapter that a certain change on the button has been made on [position] item?

Comment: Not really, you just need to know the position and then update the visibility. Check the edit I've done on my answer. Makes sense?

Comment: I dont know if im doing this right or not. On MainActivity I have the invoke method `override fun invoke(p1: Order) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Cliquei ${p1.nomeCliente}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        Adapter(arrayListPedidos,this@MainActivity).changeButtonVisibility(true,0)
    }` The Toast works just fine, I dont know if im doing the changeButtonVisibility thing right tho

Comment: From that code that you showed, it would switch between visible/invisible just by clicking, but the click doesnt have effect. From what i've understood

Comment: I made it work by putting `holder.buttonDados.visibility = if (isVisibleMap[position] == true) {
                View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                View.GONE
            }` inside the clickListener

Comment: Calling the changeButtonVisibility from outside the adapter is not updating the View. I've check through println's and the value is being updated but the view isnt. It sends the value and the variable on the adapter is being changed but its just not updating